# How to to get coordinates from addresses coming in from importrange?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange, google-apps-script-triggers, geocoding

I have addresses coming in from `importrange` and I am using this script to get coordinates.

```
function myFunction() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Geo 4')

var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var cells = range.getValues();

var latitudes = [];
var longitudes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
var address = cells[i][11];
  
if (address == "") {
latitudes.push([""]);
longitudes.push([""]);
} else {
var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(address);  
  
  
  
var res = geocoder.results[0];
if(res){
latitudes.push([res.geometry.location.lat]);
longitudes.push([res.geometry.location.lng]);
}
else
{
latitudes.push([0]);
longitudes.push([0]);
}
}

sheet.getRange('O1').offset(0, 0, latitudes.length).setValues(latitudes)
sheet.getRange('P1').offset(0, 0, latitudes.length).setValues(longitudes);
}
}
```

The issue is that I have this running on a trigger every 6 hours but I need something that would get coordinates as soon as one address changes without running the whole column and using the 1000 geocodes you get per day. I have about 350 addresses constantly but maybe three change a day.

Answer (score 1):

A spreadsheet recalculation, like the one that makes `IMPORTRANGE` results be updated, usually will not activate a trigger, only changes made by the user using the Google Sheets UI or changes to the spreadsheet structure like inserting a row. How about the following algorithm?

Preparation

1. Make a copy of the results of `IMPORTRANGE`

   This could be done manually or by using a another script function.

On every time-driven trigger execution

1. Read the current results of `IMPORTRANGE` from the spreadsheet and the values from the copy of the results of `IMPORTRANGE`
2. Using a loop

   1. Compare one by one the current results of `IMPORTRANGE` with the copy of the results of `IMPORTRANGE`
   2. For each result that have changed, get the coordinates
   3. For each result that have not changed do nothing
3. Update the spreadsheet

   1. Replace the old with a copy of the results of `IMPORTRANGE`
   2. Replaces the old coordinates with the new coordinates

Comment: Sorry Im new to scripts and writing code. I familiarized myself with some stuff using google and this website. I tried googling the steps to your solution  and think the scripts for this is out of my range.